# Jenkins build fails after reactjs test completes and all pass

Tags: reactjs, jenkins

I have a Jenkins stage for unit tests that runs

`CI=true yarn test -u --passWithNoTests --collectCoverage --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit`

The `yarn test` runs the npm script `react-script test`. I get an all pass, granted there are some warnings, but nothing shows a fail. If I comment out the test stage it makes it through the next stages so something is tripping it up here but I can't pinpoint what.

All the "warnings" look like:

```
console.error
    warning: ...
```

At the end of the tests I get:

```
Test Suites: 40 passed, 40 total
Tests:       2 todo, 179 passed, 181 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        88.729 s
Ran all test suites.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // nodejs
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] echo
hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 1
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: FAILURE
```

Am I missing something? Is there something I can add to the command to provide more details.

Comment: I removed yarn and switched to strictly `npm` and it still fails but that `error Command failed with exit code 1.` error doesn't show. However, the `hudsun` error still occurs.